# AngularJS : Conditional tooltip trigger

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need a tooltip to show up when the used entered value in one text field is greater than 100.
 I have the following code:
`tooltip="Some Message" tooltip-trigger="{{{true: 'mouseenter', false: 'never'}[text.field > 100]}}"`

The issue is that the tooltip never gets tiggered, even if I see that the trigger value changes from never to mouseenter (in the inspect element) when text.field > 100.
What am I missing here?

Comment: try tooltip-trigger="mouseenter", tooltip-enable="{{text.field > 100}}". from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip

Comment: @stomo21 - Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should be moving the tooltip logic to angular function and use show/hide event for tooltip based on the value user entered rather than on html template